# Code completion of android studio not working anymore

Tags: android, android-studio

this morning android studio is giving me this error:

```
com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsTypeParameterImpl cannot be cast to com.intellij.psi.PsiReferenceList:
```

and as result i can't use code completion or browse methods/variables of my objects anymore.

I reported that error to google of course, but i need to solve it now because there is no retro compatibilty from android studio to eclipse, i just cant work anymore.

Anyone has any tip ?

Comment: What is your environement? Java / AndroidStudio version etc.

Comment: android studio version: AI 130.709792
java version: 1.7.0_21